# How to remove word "chapter 1" in preface

Tags: microsoft-word

I want remove chapter name 'CHAPTER 1' in front matter. How to do it?

[image]

Comment: Create a style for "preface" which is based on "heading 1"and not numbered.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried it, and success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a style for "preface" which is based on "heading 1" and not numbered.